# Where is my encoding wrong? (The letter "x95 \ x84 \ xeb \...." appears.)

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, unicode, encoding

Where is my encoding wrong? (The letter "o" appears.)

`Sys.setdefaultencoding ('utf-8')` This statement has been removed.
I use `Python 3`.

> Then the letters x95 \ x84 \ xeb \ xb0 \ xb0 \ xea \ xb3 \ xa0 \ xed \ x8c \ x8c 'come out like this.

Where is my encoding wrong?

I also find it hard to understand,

```
346 seconds: 52.25020146369934
347 seconds: 52.694828271865845
348 seconds: 52.80767774581909
349 seconds: 52.92116045951843
```

After this way, the data(tweets) comes out.
What does that mean ?

```
#py3.6
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import codecs
import sys
import importlib

importlib.reload (sys)

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS('C:\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs')
url = u'https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&vertical=default&q=%EB%B0%B0%EA%B3%A0%ED%8C%8C%20since%3A2017-07-19%20until%3A2017-07-20&l=ko&src=typd&lang=ko'

browser.get(url)
time.sleep(1)

body = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")

start = time.time()
for _ in range(5000):
    now = time.time()
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
    print (str(_) + "    seconds: " + str(now - start))
    time.sleep(0.1)

tweets=browser.find_elements_by_class_name('tweet-text')

with codecs.open("dlrjtdmstnrwp.txt", "w","utf-8") as f:
    i = 1
    for i, tweet in enumerate(tweets):
        data = tweet.text
        data = data.encode('utf-8')
        print (i, ":", data)
    msg = (str(data) +'\n')
    f.write(msg)
    i += 1

end = time.time() 
print(end - start)
browser.quit()
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the tweets' text is already unicode.
And as I understand you want to write the tweets to a file, so why are you encoding the data? why are you using `str(data)` after that?

Comment: Don't touch encoding system, `codecs.open("dlrjtdmstnrwp.txt", "w","utf-8")` read bytes and write bytes. Important point is "which encoding system is incoming ?", another think is `python3` is `unicode` so who care encoding ?

Comment: @dsgdfg 
I searched. Search results in languages ​​other than English
To write this code correctly, I was asked to write it like this: ("57: b '\ xeb \ x84 \ xb9" when the tweet appears.) How am I correcting and correct?  
The concept of encoding is lacking, and I am having trouble

Comment: @nutmeg64 
It is similar to the comment above. I can not summon two people, so I will write back. I am importing languages ​​other than English. Not English
 Internet search results were expressed in such a way that it was said. I am still
 Sadly, I do not understand your comment. This is because the concept of encoding is insufficient. Could you explain more?

Comment: If your goal is writing tweets to a file, then since Python3 handles unicode by default all you need to do is just write it to a file. It does not matter which language it is, assuming that it is supplied as unicode. If your goal is different, then please be more specific.

Comment: @nutmeg64 
**1**. I would like to bring tweets written in Korean. **2**. Using the above code, you can get all tweets from 7 days ago. Also, since it is an unlimited scrolling, you can get all your tweets (using url with keyword, date). **3**. When I see the output screen, my tweets do not mean "Hello (Korean)". It comes in strange code as I wrote above. **4**. Saved txt file also comes with strange code. **5**. I want to save it in Korean properly. How do I make corrections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an answer to a simplified version of your problem.

Since i don't know Korean, I used Google Translate. I typed 'hello' and translated this into Korean.
Then I looked at the 'inspect element' for the translation result. This is what is got:

[image: Hello tanslation in Korean]

extracting the `span` element with selenium in your case is equivalent to extracting the `tweet-text` element:

```
span = browser.find_element_by_class_name('short_text')
print(span.text)
```

This will us the result:

```
>>>안녕하세요
```

As you can see, no encoding\decoding was needed because in Python 3.x `str = unicode`.